# trying to edit group policy to allow insecure guest logons

Tags: group-policy

My boss asked me to create an app on the desktop which through PowerShell would edit the Local group policy of a user's computer, changing the options in the Local Group Policy to enable insecure guest logons. Which Language would be best for this? Is there a good way to do this that would impress him? I am pretty proficient with HTML, CSS, JavaScript and can do classes and methods with JS but really I don't know where to start. Any help would be greatly apricated!

Comment: Maybe your boss wants you to just write a small powershell script? No need for anything like python or c++.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Those scripts usually come with the file extension `*.ps`. See Microsofts [How to Write and Run Scripts in Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/how-to-write-and-run-scripts-in-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-7.3).